# How can i use TurboMail 3 together with TurboGears 2

Tags: python, email, turbogears

Hy,
I want to use TurboMail3 ([website](http://www.python-turbomail.org/wiki/3.0/BetaRelease)) together with a TurboGears 2([website](http://www.turbogears.org/2.0/)) project. Which files to I have to modify to include TurboMail into my TurboGears project? Everything I find on the web is for TurboMail2 and TurboGears1.

The TurboMail Documentation states that there actually is a TG2 integration but I never found documentation for it.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a plzsendtehcodez question?  Are you asking for someone here to write this for you?  Or do you have some specific problem or question?

Comment: Neither, there IS a integration but I dont find the documentation for it, so Im searching for someone who can tell me where I have to configure it. This should be a one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integration is currently the same as for Pylons. There is a ticket for a TG2 specific integration which is currently in our bug tracker. If you really want answers for that topic, please ask in the turbomail google group: http://groups.google.com/group/turbomail-devel

Answer (score 0):

This might help you along: [Getting TurboMail to work with TurboGears 2.0](http://www.5dollarwhitebox.org/drupal/node/92)